# How does someone using Java get json data from their local host instead of a URL?

Tags: java, json, api, url, localhost

So essentially I made my own version of [this json] (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts). But as I'm learning I can't pick it out the same way as a URL. Is there a way to retrieve my json from a local host?

```
public class Application {

    public static final String POSTS_API_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .GET()
                .header("accept", "application/json")
                .uri(URI.create(POSTS_API_URL))
                .build();
        HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        // parse JSON
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<Post> posts = mapper.readValue(response.body(), new TypeReference<List<Post>>() {
        });

        // posts.forEach(post -> {
        //     System.out.println(post.toString());
        // });
        posts.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: A localhost url is still a url, the library / code should / does not care. You should of course take care that there is actually a web server running on localhost that can handle the incoming request.

Comment: Oh. Then How would one upload there json to the local server? I tried with text, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I found a Json server installer for json database https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server